# How do I compare 3 numbers with a function that takes only 2 variables in Python with a code that I have written

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter

I have written a code in Python Jupyter with the below instructions:
Write a function which will always return the bigger of  2 unequal numbers ( do not use max or any built-in function) name it **show_max**

```
def show_max(x,y):
if(x == y):
    r = ("Both the numbers are equal")
elif(x > y):
    r = (f"{x} is the maximum number")
else:
    r = (f"{y} is the maximum number")
return(r)
```

Thereafter, I have to code as per the below instruction:
Using the **show_max** function write a code to find the biggest of 3 unequal numbers

I am unable to code the 2nd portion. Could anybody help. Thanks!!!

Comment: Your first function doesn't meet the specification, and see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3001761

Comment: If you have 3 numbers (e.g `1`, `5`, `10`) you can `show_max` on the first two numbers (`1` and `5`). Then take that return (in this case it will be `5`) and do `show_max` on the return and the other number (`5` and `10`) which would return `10`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could also use this approach:

```py
def show_max(x,y,z):
    nums = [x,y,z]
    nums.sort()
    return f"{nums[-1]} is the maximum number"
```

No need for comparisons.